# convert hash key to an integer in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a initialized a hash from a txt file. If I am not mistaken, the key is currently a string. How can I make it an integer? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
products_file = File.open("files.txt")
products = {}
while !products_file.eof?
  x, *products[x] = products_file.gets.chomp.split(",")
  a = products[x]
  a[0].strip!
  a[1] = a[1].strip.to_f
end
puts products
```

File:

```
199, Shoes, 59.99
211, Shirts, 19.99
245, Hats, 25.99
689, Coats, 99.99
712, Beanies, 6.99
```

My result is:

```
{"199"=>["Shoes", 59.99], "211"=>["Shirts", 19.99], "245"=>["Hats", 25.99], "689"=>["Coats", 99.99], "712"=>["Beanies", 6.99]}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd do `Hash[ hash.keys.map(&:to_i).zip(hash.values) ]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inject` to build a new hash with integer keys:

```
hash = {"199"=>["Shoes", 59.99], "211"=>["Shirts", 19.99]}

p hash.inject({}) { |memo, item| memo[Integer(item[0])] = item[1]; memo }
  # => {199=>["Shoes", 59.99], 211=>["Shirts", 19.99]}
```

Comment: Is there another way besides using inject?

Comment: I don't really understand inject

Comment: Check out the [documentation and examples](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.3/Enumerable#inject-instance_method), and then just go experiment with it. It's a very useful method.

Comment: When converting from file values or user input, you should use `Integer()` as it throws exceptions for malformed integers, while `to_i` returns 0.

Comment: `inject` iterates over each item in the hash performing the block on it. The return value of the previous iteration is passed to the next via `memo`. Passing `inject` an argument supplies the first iteration with something to work with. This may make the code a little more clear:

`hash = {"1" => 1, "2" => 2, "3" => 3}; p hash.inject({}){|hash, (key, value)| hash[Integer(key)] = value; return hash }`. Before the first iteration the hash is `{}`. And at the beginning of the second it's `{1 => 1}`. Beginning of the third: `{ 1 => 1, 2 => 2}`. And at the end of the third it's the desired result.

Comment: Too bad `hash.keys` doesn't have a setter. You could just do: `hash.keys = hash.keys.map(&:to_i)`.